# overloaded function with parameter double called over float or decimal

Tags: .net, double, decimal, overloading

When in .net I create three overloaded function for "Add" with parameters float, double and decimal. Why is that it always call double and not others? I am just trying to understand the reason of precedence.

```
 public Form1()
 {
     var g = Add(4.5, 5.6);
 }

 public object Add(float a, float b)
 {
         return a + b;
 }

 public object Add(double a, double b)
 {
        return a + b;
 }

 public object Add(decimal a, decimal b)
 {
     return a + b;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `4.5` and `5.6` are `double` literals, the call is bound to the overload with double parameters.

To call the overload with float parameters:

```
var g = Add(4.5f, 5.6f);
```

To call the overload with decimal parameters:

```
var g = Add(4.5m, 5.6m);
```

Comment: I feel so stupid for not trying it without decimal and float. Thanks :)

Comment: Now, what happens when an integer (`1)` literal is used, a long (`1L`)? :}

Comment: @user2864740 the compiler will choose the overload with parameter type that your integer can be implicitly converted to, but you'll probably get an ambiguous call error in OPs example with `1` because multiple overloads would fit that bill.